# How to extract the text followed by some pattern using regex?

Tags: regex

I have some text like below:

- R A1 TL 103R BLIZZAK DM-V2 XL FP
- R 18 TL 103Y POTENZA S001 XL
- R 15C TL 104/102S DURAVIS R660

From these text I need to extract only

- BLIZZAK DM-V2 XL FP
- POTENZA S001 XL
- DURAVIS R660

I am not comfortable working with `regex`. I tried following patterns and I am kind of lost

```
[A-Z] [0-9A-Z]{4}
```

Can anybody please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\b[0-9A-Z]{4}\s+(.+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NbPSS5/1). Capturing group 1 will hold the  value you need.

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[0-9A-Z]{4}`  - four chars that are either uppercase letters or digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars, other than line break chars, as many as possible.

As an answer to [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62210943/how-to-extract-the-text-followed-by-some-pattern-using-regex/62210981?noredirect=1#comment110025742_62210981), you may consider

```
^(?:\S+\s+){4}(.+)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NbPSS5/2). It matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\S+\s+){4}` -  four occurrences of 1+ non-whitespace chars followed with 1+ whitespace chars
- `(.+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars, other than line break chars, as many as possible.

Comment: @SS Yes? What exactly?

Comment: Is it possible to change {4} fixed to something between 1-4. Because in some cases I have R A1 TL 13R BLIZZAK DM-V2 XL FP

Comment: @SS Maybe you can use a regex to grab all after four occurrences of 1+ non-whitespace chars followed with 1+ whitespace chars?